# Mime type for time-stamped text in gstreamer subtitleoverlay element

Tags: c, gstreamer

According to the documentation, the [subtitleoverlay](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-subtitleoverlay.html) element supports timestamped text. Is there a standard for times tamped text supported by this element? If yes, what is the mime type and the expected format?

I was able to render raw text read from a file on top of the video using the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-0.10 videotestsrc ! \
    subtitleoverlay name=ovl ! \
    autovideosink \
    filesrc location=test.txt ! text/plain !  ovl.
```

But this just renders static text, not dynamic text based on the time stamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the trick is to specify the mime type of the subtitle file.  Here are a few that the source code indicates are supported:

```
application/x-subtitle
application/x-subtitle-sami
application/x-subtitle-tmplayer
application/x-subtitle-mpl2
application/x-subtitle-dks
application/x-subtitle-qttext
application/x-subtitle-lrc
```

The pipeline for an SRT subtitles file:

> gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=YOURVIDEO ! decodebin ! videoconvert !
>   subtitleoverlay name=o ! videoconvert ! autovideosink filesrc
>   location=SUBTITLES.srt ! application/x-subtitle ! o.

SUBTITLES.srt:

```
1
00:00:00,140 --> 00:00:00,900
Some text from 140 milliseconds in, to 900 milliseconds.

2
00:00:01,000 --> 00:00:02,000
And more text starting at one second in.
```

The Matroska site has some good info:

http://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/srt.html

http://www.matroska.org/technical/specs/subtitles/ssa.html

For the ssa format it looks like you need to have libass installed and it's part of gst-plugins-bad:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-assrender.html

The source can be found in the gst-plugins-base package.

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-plugins-base.html

Start here:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/gst/playback/gstsubtitleoverlay.c

And the actual subtitle parsing code seems to be in here:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/gst/subparse

Comment: `application/x-subtitle` did the trick for srt files. Thanks. Can you point me to the source code file that you mentioned?